# Array of immutable objects initialized at compile-time

Tags: java, beginner

I have a class that contains defines 'magic' numbers at compile time such as basic array sizes, fixed ip address, etc. so that I have one place to edit if changes are required.

In this nested class I need to define tuples of maximum and minimum values that correspond to each of 4 bands of an IR camera.  I'd like to use the data like this (for readability):

```
int x = lutBounds[3].min;
```

Is my code below considered 'good practice'?  If not, why, and what would be better.  I'm completely self-taught in Java but try to use 'best practices' when I can recognize them.

```
/**
 * LUTBounds holds a band datum for the upper and lower bounds of interest.
 * @author programmer
 *
 */
 static class LUTBounds {
    final int   min;
    final int   max;

    LUTBounds(final int min, final int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;

    }

}

// usage: int x = lutBounds[3].min;
final static LUTBounds[]    lutBounds   = { new LUTBounds(14_123, 30_123),
        new LUTBounds(14_922, 40_123), new LUTBounds(14_815, 41_123),
        new LUTBounds(14_300, 40_123) };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest an `enum`: they're made to encapsulate a set of distinct values known at compile time. For example, this might be the code you have as a result:

```
public enum CameraInformation {

    First(14_123, 30_123, "http://google.com"),
    Second(14_922, 40_123, "http://google.com"),
    Third(14_815, 41_123, "http://google.com"),
    Fourth(14_300, 40_123, "http://google.com");

    private final int min, max;
    private final String address;

    CameraInformation(int min, int max, String address) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

The main reason for doing this is because I don't like the 0-based array index with the 1-based cameras: `lutBounds[3]` refers to camera 4 instead of 3, thus losing some expressiveness even for people familiar with this.

Using an enum also takes care of you having to choose a place to create those boundary values and passing them around: the enum is created once, stores its values in a central place and can be used anywhere you want.

Usage is easy:

```
int min = CameraInformation.Third.getMin();
```

Comment: I agree with the numbering.  The engineer who created the camera counts from zero when sending the number but commands to the camera start with 1.  It already bit me once!

Answer (score 3):

In no case I'd recommend an array. Arrays are mutable and your `final static LUTBounds[]` is no constant. Guava's [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) is the way to go (unless you prefer an `enum`). Because of the 1-based problem, I wouldn't expose the list, but rather a getter `getLutBoundByOneBasedIndex(int)` or something similarly terribly named, so I'd be always reminded of the insanity.

Given that the bounds probably never change, I'd prefer an enum just like in the other answer. Just don't forget that `ordinal()` is -based, in case you ever need it. Using project [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) (which I'm a big fan of), you can shrink it considerably.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor @Getter
public enum CameraInformation {
    First(14_123, 30_123, "http://google.com"),
    Second(14_922, 40_123, "http://google.com"),
    Third(14_815, 41_123, "http://google.com"),
    Fourth(14_300, 40_123, "http://google.com");

    private final int min, max;
    private final String address;
}
```

Comment: I forgot that I could iterate though the enums with Java's for-loop.  I'll look at lombok.